# ¿Qué significa "llamar cama" en "no conocían a nadie que se llamara cama el remitente"?

Tags: modismos

De *Cien años de soledad*:

> Tanto los nombres mencionados como la firma de la carta eran
>   perfectamente legibles, pero ni José Arcadio Buendía ni Úrsula
>   recordaban haber tenida parientes con esos nombres ni conocían a nadie
>   que se **llamara cama** el remitente y mucha menos en la remota población
>   de Manaure.

El contexto en inglés es traducido:

> The names mentioned, as well as the signature on the letter, were
>   perfectly legible, but neither José Arcadio Buendía nor Úrsula
>   remembered having any relatives with those names, nor did they know
>   anyone **by the name of** the sender of the letter, much less the remote
>   village of Manaure.

Pero qué significa llamar cama por lo general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un error tipográfico que por lo que se ve está repetido en muchos lugares. Es *que se llamara **como** el remitente*. No tengo el libro a mano pero así aparece [en Google Books](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=QBwnDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT51&lpg=PT51&dq=%22ni%20Jos%C3%A9%20Arcadio%20Buend%C3%ADa%20ni%20%C3%9Arsula%20recordaban%20haber%20tenido%20parientes%20con%20esos%20nombres%20ni%20conoc%C3%ADan%20a%20nadie%20que%20se%20llamara%20como%20el%20remitente%22&source=bl&ots=mVSJvRQFPa&sig=mgtbJ_J57U4detUzmXbyGo3XhIk&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSyujZtPvYAhXBnJAKHfyzDcUQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=%22ni%20Jos%C3%A9%20Arcadio%20Buend%C3%ADa%20ni%20%C3%9Arsula%20recordaban%20haber%20tenido%20parientes%20con%20esos%20nombres%20ni%20conoc%C3%ADan%20a%20nadie%20que%20se%20llamara%20como%20el%20remitente%22&f=false).

Comment: ah, debe ser un mal auto-correct en word o algo así.

Comment: ¡Qué bueno verte por aquí de nuevo, Pablo!

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Gracias!

Comment: @walen que buen ojo. No me lo he fijado en esto! "Me thinks" es tiempo buscar otra versión.

Comment: A small screenshot of the section via Amazon Kindle: https://imgur.com/a/I67bn